# xymatrix and cartesian product

Tags: xymatrix

I am using this to produce a diagram

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{H_n(X;R) \ar[d]^{f_*}&  \times  & H^m(X;R) \ar[r] & H_{n-m}(X;R) \ar[d]^{f_*} \\
H_n(X;R)&  \times  & H^m(X;R)\ar[u]_{f^*} \ar[r]  &H_{n-m}(Y;R)}
\]

\end{document}
```

because I want an arrow between each component of the product. How can I suppress the space on each side of \times ?

Comment: That said, I don't think `xy` can do that. You can with `tikzcd` (which I'd recommend over `xy` nowadays, more features, nicer arrows). But it would probably just be easier to x shift the arrows instead. AFAIR `xy` can do this as well.

Comment: You mean that way ?

Comment: Thank you I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `xy` can do what you ask, but `tikz-cd` can. Though I'd probably just use the `xshift` solution (second `tikzcd` example).

The `xy` equivalent for `xshift` can be seen in section 2.4 in the `xy` manual (`xyguide.pdf`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % if you are using a language that makes " an active char
\begin{document}

Standard xy:
\[
\xymatrix{H_n(X;R) \ar[d]^{f_*}&  \times  & H^m(X;R) \ar[r] & H_{n-m}(X;R) \ar[d]^{f_*} \\
H_n(X;R)&  \times  & H^m(X;R)\ar[u]_{f^*} \ar[r]  &H_{n-m}(Y;R)}
\]

Tikzcd with column space adjustment:
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    H_n(X;R) \arrow[d,"f_*"] &[-3em]  \times  &[-3em] H^m(X;R) \arrow[r] &  H_{n-m}(X;R) \arrow[d, "f_*"]
    \\
    H_n(X;R)&  \times  & H^m(X;R)\arrow[u,"f^*"] \ar[r]  &H_{n-m}(Y;R)\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Tikzcd using xshift instead:
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    H_n(X;R)    \times   H^m(X;R) \arrow[d,"f_*",xshift=-2em]  \arrow[r] &  H_{n-m}(X;R) \arrow[d, "f_*"]
    \\
    H_n(X;R)  \times   H^m(X;R)\arrow[u,"f^*",xshift=2em] \ar[r]  &H_{n-m}(Y;R)\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slide arrows; use the amount you think best.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{H_n(X;R) \times H^m(X;R) \ar@<-2.5em>[d]_{f_*} \ar[r] & H_{n-m}(X;R) \ar[d]^{f_*} \\
H_n(X;R) \times H^m(X;R) \ar@<-2.5em>[u]_{f^*} \ar[r] & H_{n-m}(Y;R)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without “thumb computation”:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\newlength{\shiftA}
\newlength{\shiftB}

\begin{document}

\[
\settowidth{\dimen0}{$H_n(X;R)$}
\settowidth{\dimen2}{$H^m(X;R)$}
\settowidth{\dimen4}{${}\times{}$}
\setlength{\shiftA}{\dimexpr(\dimen0+\dimen4)/2}
\setlength{\shiftB}{\dimexpr(\dimen2+\dimen4)/2}
\xymatrix{H_n(X;R) \times H^m(X;R) \ar@<-\shiftA>[d]_{f_*} \ar[r] & H_{n-m}(X;R) \ar[d]^{f_*} \\
H_n(X;R) \times H^m(X;R) \ar@<-\shiftB>[u]_{f^*} \ar[r] & H_{n-m}(Y;R)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]